# How to handle changes in compile-time constants in Java libraries for consistent results?

Tags: java, compiler-optimization

Here is an example:

This is a class in my project:

```
class MyProject {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println(A.COMPILE_TIME_CONSTANTS);
   }
}
```

This is a class in library A：

```
class Library A {
    public static final String COMPILE_TIME_CONSTANTS = "compile_time_constants_version_0";
}
```

This is a class in library B：

```
class Library B {
    void b() {
        System.out.println(A.COMPILE_TIME_CONSTANTS);
    }
}
```

My project references the compile-time constant `COMPILE_TIME_CONSTANTS` from library A. Because of  the inline optimization, after compilation, `COMPILE_TIME_CONSTANTS` in my project will be replaced with the string `"compile_time_constants_version_0"`. When library A is upgraded, regardless of whether the constant value has changed or not, I just need to recompile the project code to avoid inconsistencies caused by inlining of compile-time constants.

Everything is ok up to now. Problem comes when another library B in my project also references `COMPILE_TIME_CONSTANTS` from library A (I don't know their dependency relationship, so I won't upgrade library B), and the value of `COMPILE_TIME_CONSTANTS` in library A changes from `"compile_time_constants_version_0"` to `"compile_time_constants_version_1"`. Because library is pre-compiled, even if I recompile the project, library B still uses the old value `"compile_time_constants_version_0"`.

My question:

1. It should be the responsibility of the project developers or the library developers to avoid this issue?
2. And How?

Comment: *"I don't know their dependency relationship, so I won't upgrade library B"* - so, why does it matter if B uses an old value of A? Does any part of your code rely on some part of A for input to B which in turn depends on B's "knowledge" of A? In practice, if libraries depend on each other you *do* need to be aware of it and handle it properly.

Comment: It is best not to export compile-time constants as part of an API if you assume that these values could change. Do not rely on a library that exports compile-time constants as part of their API with changing values.

Comment: @luk2302 If my code calls `B#b()` eigher directly or through a deep call path, `B#b()` will print the old value, which is unexpected. In pratice, it's usually hard to know dependency relationship among libraries. In a gradle project, for example, some libraries may be included into proejct due to transive dependency.